# Spring Boot JPA with Dynamic Table and column

Tags: database, spring-boot, spring-mvc, dynamicquery, dynamic-tables

How to run SQL query in spring boot when my tables' name is dynamic and the number of the columns of the table is also dynamic/varying depending on the requirement.

While using `entity class` we require to set static table and column names.

Eg-

Table- FunndTransfer_Category1 have columns - id,name,amount,**abc**

Table- FunndTransfer_Category2 have columns - id,name,amount,**xyz**

here column name abc,xyz will add at time of table creation when user upload it.

Is there any alternate approach to run query??

Comment: You need to explain further. When you say dynamic, do you mean that the names may change/are random (in which case you need to rethink your data model) or that you have some equivalent tables that you wish to query (again, think about normalisation and consolidation) or something completely different, in which case you need to provide more information. [ask]

Comment: If you have dynamic tables JPA is the wrong approach

Comment: Which method should I follow?

Answer (score 1):

you can use something as below

```
     @PersistenceContext
     private EntityManager entityManager;

     List<Object> getData(){
        String tableName = "FunndTransfer_Category1";
        Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from "+tableName);
        return query.getResultList();
     }
```